# Object in an array in another class

Tags: java, constructor

How can I do for: when I create an object in main class for example

```
public class Blabla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Whatever w = new Whatever(100, 200, 400);
        Whatever w2 = new Whatever(500, 600, 700);
    }
}
```

It will be added automatically in an array in another class for example in

```
public class Pilipili {
    private Whatever[] tabW = new Whatever[20];
}
```

I hope that my question is clear enough!

Comment: No, your question is not clear enough.

Comment: I didn't get, either.

Comment: You need to specify the relationship of X to Y.

Comment: Sorry, i've changed the code

Comment: It's an array of X objects

Comment: Are you sure you want an array? What if more than 20 Whatevers are created? A list would probably be better.

Comment: Yes, by the way, I'm doin' a mini-project about simple arrays. If I had a choice, it would better be ArrayList(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, what you want to achieve is that whenever you create an instance of `WhatEver` class in your `main` method, you want the new instance to be *automatically* added to an array in the `Pilipili` class; you don't want to explicitly call a method in `main` to add this new instance.

To do this, I'm giving you the overall structure of the approach with comments that you can replace with code. You need to have a `addWhateverObject` method in `Pilipili` class.

```
public void addWhateverObject(WhatEver w){   
  // Add the object w to the array tabW 
}
```

Then in `WhatEver` class, inside the constructor, you need to call the `addWhateverObject` method and pass it the `this` reference.

```
public WhatEver(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2){
  // Initialize the instance
  // Create an instance of Pilipili class
  // Call "addWhateverObject" method with "this" as the argument
}
```

Comment: Yaay! Thank yall! I've done it with a simple array. But, I have one more question. By the way, `Pilipili` it's `Company`. Can I make fields and methods as static and in the constructor I make Company.add(this)?

Comment: See my answer. You don't want to do it in the constructor, you want to do it after the constructor. But since you don't want the caller to have to do it, you need an intermediate level: a static factory method.

Comment: Yes you 'can' make them static, but static methods/variables should be used when you really need them; as they create single instances across your application, they could lead to complex bugs in your code. As in your code, I think what you really need is a single instance of the `Pilipili` class that can be achieved using the singleton pattern. For now, may be you can use `static` variable, but do read about singleton pattern to see how it will fit in your problem.

Comment: The best way to make a singleton, by the way, is with an enum with just a single value.

Comment: And do read about the problem's that may arise in complex situations as discussed in the answer by @DavidConrad. They may not be necessary for you right now, but will help you understand the finer details.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass X values to the other class constructor or create a method in the other class like:

```
class AnotherClass {

    X[] xArray = new X[20]

    void setXArrayItem(X x, int index) {
       xArray[index] = x;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you cannot bind a class in this way that whenever its object created it automatically passed to an array or whatever datastructure you are using. you have to write a method which you can call on the creation of object explicitly.

Comment: means you have to call some function of class `Pilipili` which will set your `w` and `w2` object in the array. you cant associate the creation of object to some datastructure

Comment: I know, but I can't find an idea!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this ...

```
public class Blabla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Whatever w = new Whatever(100, 200, 400);
        Whatever w2 = new Whatever(500, 600, 700);
    }
}

public class Whatever{
    public Whatever(){int i, int j, int k){
        // some code
        Pilipili.addTabW(this);
    }
}

public class Pilipili {
    private static List<Whatever> tabW = new ArrayList<Whatever>();
    public static void addTabW(Whatever w){
        tabW.add(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty much like this. I've done in simple arrays. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be if Whatever had a class variable that referred to Pilipili, and called it at the end of the constructor to register the new object.

```
public class Blabla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Whatever.registry = new Pilipili();

        Whatever w1 = new Whatever(100, 200, 400);
        Whatever w2 = new Whatever(500, 600, 700);
    }
}

public class Whatever {
    public static Pilipili registry;

    private final int alpha, bravo, charlie;

    public Whatever(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.alpha = a;
        this.bravo = b;
        this.charlie = c;

        if (registry != null) {
            registry.register(this);
        }
    }
}

public class Pilipili {
    private int next = 0;
    private Whatever[] tabW = new Whatever[20];

    public void register(Whatever w) {
        tabW[next++] = w;
    }
}
```

However, this isn't considered safe. The Whatever constructor should not allow a reference to the object to escape before construction is finished. In a simple case like this it wouldn't matter, but if the fields were final and the object was used from multiple threads, the guarantee that all threads would see the values set to the final fields would not be assured. That guarantee is only made once the constructor finishes. Since the other class would be able to see the object before construction was complete, it could potentially see it in an inconsistent state.

The best way to get around this is to restructure your code so that it isn't necessary, but the next best way is to make the constructor private and create the objects with a factory method. That way, the factory method can call the constructor, then, after the constructor has completed, it can register the objects with listeners or what have you, and then it can return the constructed and registered object to the caller.

```
public class Blabla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Whatever.registry = new Pilipili();

        Whatever w1 = Whatever.newInstance(100, 200, 400);
        Whatever w2 = Whatever.newInstance(500, 600, 700);
    }
}

public class Whatever {
    public static Pilipili registry;

    private final int alpha, bravo, charlie;

    private Whatever(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.alpha = a;
        this.bravo = b;
        this.charlie = c;
    }

    public static Whatever newInstance(int a, int b, int c) {
        Whatever whatever = new Whatever(a, b, c);

        if (registry != null) {
            registry.register(whatever);
        }

        return whatever;
    }
}
```

Again, this is safe because by the time the static factory method registers the instance with Pilipili, the constructor has already returned. It is then safe for a reference to the newly constructed object to escape to the outside world.

Comment: Isn't pretty much difficult? I found the solution, by check my answer about static fields/methods. I need help about that.

Comment: It's just one more, fairly simple, method. Doesn't seem very difficult to me, and it avoids the problem of letting references escape before the constructor has completed. If you want to simplify it, it could just blindly call a certain static method of Pilipili (say, `Pilipili.add()`) instead of having some other code set it up with a `registry` -- I included that in case the place to put the instances needed to be configurable.

Comment: Yes, you can make fields and methods static. For instance, Whatever.registry is static, or I could have made Pilipili's next and tabW fields static and its register() method static.